# Add another checkbox column while using Wrapper?

Tags: visualforce, wrapper-class

I'm using a wrapper to load a list of records into a VF page that I can select (to add to a related record).  I'd like to add another column of checkboxes that the user can select for a different value (not on the original object that is listed).  If this checkbox is selected, I'll create another related record.  How can I make sure I grab the correct IDs for the rows?

Comment: Have you tried adding another boolean value in the wrapper class?

Comment: can you post your code whatever you have tried so far